# How to set specific range in start monitoring beacon region ? (iOS)

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to set the range when user enter the region using the app. 
For example, I entering region in 300m far from the beacon ( now, this distance is based on the beacon signal strength ). And then, the notification comes. 
In this case, my app is killed. So, I using **`startMonitoring()`.**

My questions are :
1. is that possible to **set the maximum distance** to entering the region? if yes, how to set it ?

2. If **I already enter the region**, then **I kill the app**. How to give notification that I already enter the region ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/determining_the_proximity_to_an_ibeacon refer this link

Comment: it only explain the proximity distance using ranging. But it not covered my question.  my question is using monitoring.

Comment: You cannot set a trigger distance for a beacon region; the beacon is either visible (in which case you are in the region) or not (in which case you aren't) .  You can call `determineStateForRegion` to as iOS to tell you whether you are currently inside or outside the region